# Question about drivers to Dell i3510

Tags: drivers, dell, touchpad

I need your help. What is the official deb update source for Ubuntu 22.04? I have a Dell Inspiron 13 i5310 laptop with an 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-11370H @ 3.30GHz processor, and I need to optimize the system because I'm experiencing some issues such as touchpad freezing and the battery.

Can you tell me what is the correct source to add to my system or drivers?

Comment: Ubuntu offers kernel stack choice for LTS releases; the most *stable* is the GA kernel stack, the *latest* however is the HWE kernel stack. There are also some OEM options for specific hardware which provide a better experience for particular hardware. Switching kernel changes kernel modules; with kernel modules commonly being called *drivers*. The installation media used will dictate the default kernel stack being used.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Sounds like you may have an actual question. You may want to ask that. From your question  issues such as touchpad freezing and the battery.

Comment: Hi thanks por your response!, i download and install my version with a usb. i read in others post something name "xinput" for the touch pad, what do you do think.

Answer (score 0):

Dell doesn't have an official update source for Ubuntu Desktop packages. Dell advises its Ubuntu users to use the default Ubuntu repositories for software sources instead.

Results of `apt show xinput` :

```
Runtime configuration and test of XInput devices 
Xinput is an utility for configuring and testing XInput  devices.
```

For more information visit: [Adjust your touchpad on Linux using xinput](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu-sn&q=xinput+touchpad)

Comment: thanks, i read in others posts and talk something name "xinput" what you thing?

Comment: @Davincho I added my reply to your comment to my answer.